# Don't make Laravel / PHP wait for python script to finish

Tags: php, laravel, hierarchy

**Current setup**

I currently have a controller class called `HomeController.php` creates a `request` for the details the user enters in a form as well as saving other details (Which is not part of this problem).

This `request` is then sent to another controller class `Jobcontroller.php` which runs the API, `careerjet` and returns `urls`

**The problem**

I have to manually need to visit another page to run an the API and get the results, then having to execute the python scripts. IE:

```
website.co.uk/output -> URL 1 , URL 2 , URL 3
exec(script1.py)
exec(script2.py)
exec(script3.py)
```

**What i'm trying to achieve**

I do not want to do this of course, and need everything to be automated. Meaning, if the user clicks `submit`, the api code will immediately run and then the python scripts **and** it shouldn't affect the front-end usability speed. (They don't have to linger on the same page, waiting for the last job to finish).

I looked at queues implementation for this - and it seems that it only runs when theres no other requests.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an architecture type of question, but you can try these options:

**1. Create a Separate Python Application and communicate via an API**

If synchronous operation is mandatory, you may want to have your python scripts be executable via an API. Simply host your scripts via something like Flask.

When Laravel sends an API request to the Flask application, it will kick off the script, and return the result via the HTTP API.

**2. Execute the Job in a Queue**

So basically same flow as above, but actually create a Laravel `Job` that communicates to this Flask Application *in the background*. The user can continue about their business in the Laravel application, when the `Job` is complete, you can update your database, send a notification, whatever.

**3. Execute the Python Script via a PHP shell command**

I don't recommend this approach for a long term solution, but you could have PHP execute a shell command that kicks off your python script.

Having the script communicate back to the PHP application could be a total pain in the ass. But it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for telling me this :). I don't have time to refactor my code base, so i just implement a `job` and run python scripts via that.

Would I be able to implement the `careerjetAPI` via this? EG: By calling the controller class or would i need to refactor and implement this as well

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. What you can do is put your logic to communicate with the CareerJet API in a Laravel Job. Try following a Laravel Job/Queue tutorial and see how it works.